# Email address of user using Google analytics

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can I get the email address of the user who visited my site in google analytics? My web site is in asp.net

Comment: Why do you think this is possible? Think about privacy issues? And what have you tried to find for yourself?

Comment: If I knew a site was mining my address (without my permission), I'd probably never visit...

Comment: Forget email, I would rather ask google for SSNs of all my visitors

Comment: Pretty sure google analytics does not use email addresses, plus invasion of privacy will not be taken well by your visitors!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is to ask the customer for their email address as part of something on your site, then record the IP address along with it.  Then you can tie that IP to the analytics.

There's certainly no way to pull it from the analytics themselves.

Comment: I have came to know visitor level customization in one of the google anayltics page

Comment: Here is the example of what I mean..Can any one try to help me to get the email address from the linkhttps://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingCustomVariables?hl=en_GB#examples

Comment: @ManojChowdary - No, you need to ask the user for their email address, *then* include it in one of those variables (which you can do by following the example).  If you don't ask them, there's no way to get it.

Comment: Hi Bobson can you give the example..i cant find it in the  comment of ours

Comment: Look on the page you linked.  Find the section called "Async Snippet".  Copy that into your code.  Replace "Sub-Section" with "Email Address".  Replace "Fashion" with the user's email.  You're on your own for asking the user for their email so you know what to put in that field.  I won't help with that.